# Rails news filter url seo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, parameters

I want to set

```
abc.com/news?street=2&area=3$price=6
```

to

```
abc.com/news-2-3-6
```

the params street,area and price are all  optional

My routes likes

```
match "/news(-:street-:area-:price)"  => "news#index",:as => :news_index
```

It not work well.

Comment: "It not work well." What's the problem?

Comment: When i click <%= link_to street.name,params.merge(:street => street) %>
i get url like "news?street=1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two technical problems with your route, and one big problem I'll mention as well.

First, you're adding a single optional segment `(-:street-:area-:price)`, meaning either all terms must appear, or none.  If you want each segment to be optional, you need to do this:

```
match "/news(-:street(-:area(-:price)))" => "news#index"
```

Secondly, you're not specifying which kinds of characters each of the terms can contain. In your example, `news-2-3-6` will wind up setting `:street` to "2-3-6", and leaving `:area` and `:price` empty. You need to tell the route which kinds of characters to accept for each variable segment. The following allows each one to contain 1 or more digits:

```
match "/news(-:street(-:area(-:price)))" => "news#index",
  :street => /\d+/, :area => /\d+/, :price => /\d+/
```

But neither of these fixes will help in the long run. This kind of "search" URL is a really bad idea because each segment depends on the existence of the previous segment(s). What I mean is, it is impossible to supply a `:price` without `:area` *and* `:street`, and impossible to supply a `:area` without a `:price`. To specify only a `:price`, your URL will have to look like `/news-0-0-6`.

Your reason for doing this is also fundamentally flawed. This is *not* SEO. A URL containing hyphen-separated numeric segments is *worse* for SEO than a URL containing a traditional query string. At least the traditional query string contains *some* indexable terms, like `street` and `price`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I know the url like this is not well, but many people say url with params is not a good idea , is there another way?

Comment: @doabit Those people are wrong. In the case of a search URL, the query string is your best option.

Comment: Hi,this is a products filter page.Thank you very much for your help!